# Redirecting old domain after copy of live store for dev

Tags: redirect, development

To create test site for copy of live store,

- Copy all files (except some media files)
- Dump and Import database
- Clear all cache (rm -rf newdomain/www/var/*)
- Update base url

UPDATE core_config_data SET value="http://newdomain.com" WHERE path=’web/secure/base_url’;

UPDATE core_config_data SET value="http://newdomain.com" WHERE path=’web/unsecure/base_url’;

(also checked select * from core_config_data where path like '%base_url%')

- Update local.xml file (for connecting test db, db user, password)
- Check root's htaccess file (I even try to delete the file)
- Asked server support , they said it's web source problem , not server setting

I think I did everything I know and search to solve! but still when I visit my test website, it still redirect my live web site

Am I missing something? What I should check more?

Comment: Url should have the '/' after '.com'. eg `http://newdomain.com/`

Comment: Also the page may be cache, did you test in a different browser?

Comment: @R.S I just checked again, my url clearly have '.com/' on core_config_data Thanks anyway

Comment: @R.S Yes I tried different browser, clear browser cache, even tried with other computer

Comment: I know you cleared cache by deleting files, but isbit posible you have folder permission issue, and cache is going to /tmp? What happens if you disable cache (use n98-magerun from cli)

Comment: @ProxiBlue Thanks for your reply! You're right after I disable cache via mysql, I can finally connect my test site. but the front-end broken..need to find the reason

Comment: Placed as answer to complete the Q/A process. Check your file perms, they may also be causing the display issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Comment copied to answer to allow this question to be marked answered, and not left hanging open, as it is solved.

I know you cleared cache by deleting files, but is it possible you have folder permission issue, and cache is going to /tmp?

What happens if you disable cache? (use n98-magerun from cli)